# Cannot read uncached files from SSD

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I have an NVMe SSD drive for games and some files.
Sometimes the drive just stops giving previously unread files - any files I used today are still there and games continue running until they have to read a new file from the drive, I can even restart them sometimes. But when I try to access a file or folder I haven't opened today it says that the file doesn't exist.
The drive still appears in "This PC" and Disk Management but not in CrystalDiskInfo.

Usually restarting my computer twice helps, sometimes for an hour, sometimes for the rest of the day, but the issue comes back.

Does this mean the drive is failing? Is it fixable? CrystalDiskInfo shows 100% score when everything is working.

Comment: The drive plugs into a controller.  Has that perhaps gone intermittent?

Comment: A few of my friends said that it may be the controller dying on the drive or on the motherboard. I moved it to another slot on the motherboard and I'll keep monitoring it

Comment: After moving to another motherboard slot the issue still happens

Comment: Post actual SMART data rather than telling us it's okay. How can Crystal Disk Info say the drive is okay while drive doesn't appear in Crystal Disk Info?

Answer (score 0):

A disk in a computer has a controller matched to the disk to run it. All disks are like this.

So even though the actual disk tests "fine", the controller for the disk has an intermittent fault.

> Does this mean the drive is failing? Is it fixable?

The only fix now is to replace the disk. It is not fixable. You cannot replace just the controller in the disk assembly.

Moving the assembly to another motherboard verifies the need for replacement.

Comment: What? Does not compute ..